# Send $_POST to masked site

Tags: php, post, masking

I have issue with sending form using PHP.

I have one page domain1.com with script and second domain2.com with masking to first domain.

The second domain domain2.com is visible in browser but the script works under domain1.com

I try send $_POST data from domain2.com to itself, but the $_POST cannot be delivered.

The form head look likes this:

```
<form method="post" action="http://<?php echo $_SERVER["HTTP_HOST"].$_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"] ?>">
```

Then I try var_dump $_POST, but is it NULL.

Me question is: How can i catch $_POST data from masked domain? Is there some hack maybe?

Any idea helps, thank to all.

Example1:

```
<form method="post" action="http://domain2.com">
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="1" />
<input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

Example2:

```
<form method="post" action="http://domain1.com">
<input type="hidden" name="data" value="1" />
<input type="submit" value="send" />
</form>
```

Comment: looks like you want to hack a site... but it won't work that way...

Comment: No I don't want hack anything. But I have more domains under one script and i want send the data to primary domain.

Comment: you're not "Masking" domain2. it'll be visible in the browser' address bar when the form gets submitted, and definitely be visible in the html of the page containing the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Simple bottom line. The `action=` param in the form is where the `$_POST` will be parsed/handled/whatever.

Frames are cheap, more like worthless (other ways of doing this stuff that is not frames).

AJAX and javascript is your friend.

Without JS, you may be able to have form on domain1 be submitted to domain2 where a `header()` redirect back to domain1.

A hack, yes.

Will it work, probably.

Would I sign my name to it, no.

Comment: Sure, this mean two ways: AJAX (JS) and redirect back to domain1 - send data. Yes?

Comment: Either or, yes. I am not sure what your "masking" really is because I have seen it used in a strict "framed" manner, old school style (late 1990's). More commonly a giant iframe is used. They should behave similarity.

The framing types are similar, but there are some nuisances you may need to mitigate. 

Read up on ```header()```, there are some weird things that can happen (session zapped?).

I agree w/fixing DNS and don't use masking. Otherwise, ajax is best IMHO.

Comment: What about me second example, this cannot work? Sending from other domain but to the primary domain.

Comment: The second example should work, i test similiar script.

Answer (score 1):

The short answer is that you cannot.

Masking works by using frames. It takes the path segment of the URL used to load the frameset, and uses it with a different base URL as the src to a frame. This can only trigger a GET request.

If you were in complete control of the server generating the frameset, then you could output the data into the HTML of the frameset, read it back in with JavaScript, generate a form with the data in it and then submit it (still with JS).

That would be a horrible hack, and if you had that much control over the server then you'd probably be using a properly hosted domain anyway.

Comment: Good idea, but i tought there can be solution without JS. Sending with GET isn't good idea. Maybe redirecting to primary domain and then sending the POST data. What dou you think? REDIRECTING vs GET (SSL will be used)

Comment: If you want to solve the problem properly, then get DNS set up properly, don't use masking, and have the server handle the script at the URL on the domain you are currently using as a mask.

Comment: @Quentin would that mean the visitor stays at the same domain or relocates?

Comment: They'd stay at the same domain.

Comment: Hmm, the project is based on masking, this is primary function of this project. But I accept your answer, becouse someone can have project not aimed to masking.

Comment: U don't happen to have an example of that? I'm not sure i'm getting this.

Comment: @DarkBee Sure, I updated the question with two possible solutions.

Answer (score 0):

You can't do that. This was against Cross-domain policy

Comment: can be mitigated. I agree, not awesome.